# How to pass the MetaData Fields as a condition to partition a synchronization in Realm

Tags: mongodb, react-native, synchronization, realm, metadata

#### Is it possible to pass the MetaData as a condition to partition a synchronization?

I need the partition value in sync to be different from `%%user.id` because the value that will control the partition I get from a MetaData in authentication via JWT in Realm, I tried something like `%%user.profile.puid` , but in the log I get an undefined comparison.

I added the fields in MetaData Fields in authentication via JWT, but what I need the most is the puid as it should control the partition

**In the code I can retrieve the value after authentication as expected and set it as a partition value for synchronization**

```
const credentials = Realm.Credentials.jwt(response.access_token);

const user = await app.logIn(credentials);

if (user) {
   setUserId(user.profile.puid as string); // State where it will be passed to the sync command on the partition
   setUser(user);
}
```

**In the permission configuration I didn't find any example that shows how to retrieve the MetaData value, I tried as follows...**

```json
{
  "%%partition": "%%user.profile.puid"
}
```

**But when I try to run the log on the realm it tells me that the comparison value is undefined**

```
Error:

could not evaluate sync permissions with error: cannot compare to undefined (ProtocolErrorCode=206)
Partition:

3c403***-****-****-****-*****5b1218f
```

I don't understand why in the permissions area the rule to retrieve the `puid` doesn't work because the logged in user has the data, the realm doesn't support this type of operation?

Comment: have you figured out?

Comment: unfortunately not, I had to use another approach